# sequelize.js - GetSomething() returning wrong values in a hasOne relation, but the correct one in a BelongTo

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get a `Fluxo` through a relation in my `CanaisCadastro` but the `GetFluxo()` is returning the wrong row.
If i use the foreign key in a `findOne` return the correct value.

```
async getFluxo(widgetId = 1){
        let canal = await CanaisCadastro.findOne({where: {id_canal_cadastro: widgetId}});
        let fluxo = await canal.getFluxo();
        let fluxo2 = await Fluxo.findOne({where: {id_fluxo: canal.id_fluxo}})
        console.log(
            canal.id_fluxo,  // 8 Value that i wan't
            fluxo.id_fluxo,  // 1 wrong value from GetFluxo
            fluxo2.id_fluxo, // 8 Correct value from findOne
        );
    }
```

**UPDATE**

if i replace `.hasOne` for `.belongsTo` works fine, but i don't understand why.

[Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to.js%7EBelongsTo.html) says the two is practically the same:

[image: BelongsTo]

[image: HasOne]

CanaisCadastro.js:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../config/database');
const Fluxo = require('./Fluxo');

class CanaisCadastro extends Model{}

CanaisCadastro.init({
    id_canal_cadastro:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true
    },
    descricao_canal:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    id_canal:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false
    },
    id_empresa:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false
    },
    id_fluxo:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false,
        references: Fluxo,

    },


},{
    sequelize,
    modelName:"canais_cadastro",
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps:false,
    force:false
})
CanaisCadastro.hasOne(Fluxo, {foreignKey: 'id_fluxo'}); // return wrong values
CanaisCadastro.belongsTo(Fluxo, {foreignKey: 'id_fluxo'}); // Works fine
Fluxo.hasMany(CanaisCadastro, {foreignKey: 'id_fluxo'});
module.exports = CanaisCadastro;
```

Fluxo.js:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../config/database');
class Fluxo extends Model{}

Fluxo.init({
    id_fluxo:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true
    },
    descricao:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    id_status:{
        type:Sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull:false
    },
    tipo:{
        type:Sequelize.ENUM('Padrão', 'Dialogflow'),
        allowNull:false
    },

},{
    sequelize,
    modelName:"fluxo",
    freezeTableName:true,
    timestamps:false,
    force:false
})

module.exports = Fluxo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CanaisCadastro` has a link to `Fluxo` using the field `id_fluxo` that means in terms of Sequelize `CanaisCadastro` belongs to `Fluxo` i.e. depends on it.

Keeping that in mind the associations between them should be:

```js
CanaisCadastro.belongsTo(Fluxo, {foreignKey: 'id_fluxo'});
Fluxo.hasMany(CanaisCadastro, {foreignKey: 'id_fluxo'});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still don't get when i should use `hasOne` relation. because seems like the same one.

Comment: For your models and how they are linked to each other it's semseless to degine `hasOne` because you have 1:N relationship

Comment: i only can use a `hasOne` in a 1:1?

Comment: Exactly. belongsTo/hasOne - 1:1, belongsTo/hasMany - 1:N. belongsToMany - M:N